# Unable to open netbeans 11.1 jdk 13

Tags: netbeans-11

I have installed `JDK 13` and `NetBeans 11.1` and I tried to open it but it only appears for seconds and then it is closed I tried to uninstall from the control panel but it said that it is running although I do not see it on the task manager!

**I removed it through these steps :**

- Removed the Netbeans folder from the program file
- Deleted the .nbi folder from C:\User{Current User}
- opened control panel and remove it

Anyway, I installed it again and nothing is solved! the same problem happens:(
what should I do!?

Comment: One possibility is that the path to JDK is invalid in the NetBeans configuration. If so: [1] Locate the file **netbeans.conf** which is in the **etc** directory of your NetBeans installation. [2] Open it in a text editor. [3] Locate the line containing **netbeans_jdkhome**. [4] Remove the leading '#' (if present) to uncomment the line. [5] Set the value to the path to your JDK. For me it looks like this: `netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Java\openJDK\jdk-13"`. [6] Save the file and (re)start NetBeans. Do you still have the problem?

Comment: Also, verify that you can call **java** from the command line.